# How to get Vibrate permission in instant app running on devices below 8.0?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Vibrator service is available in ***pixel devices (Android 8.0.0)*** and *not available* on ***Android 7.0***. I am using ***galaxy s8***. 
it crashes every-time phone is asked to vibrate. Here is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Method class android.os.IVibratorService$Stub$Proxy.vibrateMagnitude[int, class java.lang.String, long, int, interface android.os.IBinder, int, class java.lang.String]->void not available to instant apps
          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
          at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationProxy.readReply(PG:2)
          at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationProxy.invoke(PG:18)
          at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
          at $Proxy14.vibrateMagnitude(Unknown Source)
          at android.os.SystemVibrator.semVibrate(SystemVibrator.java:88)
          at android.os.SystemVibrator.vibrate(SystemVibrator.java:74)
          at android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:129)
          at android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:111)
          at com.atlasbrothers.natomounts.activities.CartActivity.o(Unknown Source)
          at com.atlasbrothers.natomounts.activities.CartActivity$24.onClick(Unknown Source)
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11157)
          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

*Is it a bug on supervisor or Vibration permission on the instant app is only available on Android 8.0 ?*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My bad. Googlers are pretty responsive here, I just wanted to ask them to fix supervisor bug that doesn't give Vibrate permission on the devices running below 8.0. Updated the question.

Comment: can you check this url https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html for ***Which permissions are available to an instant app?*** and there is no restriction for VIBRATE permission. if you have any issues I'd recommend filing your issue with Google, then link to it back in here It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: What version of "Google Play Services for Instant Apps" are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce this issue for Vibration permissions related to AIA, implementing `Vibrate` and `AndroidManifest.xml` entry for Vibrate permission in Feature Module, for Pre-O devices.

Nexus Android Version- 7.1.2 (N)
Google Play Services Version- 11.9.75
Google Play Services for Instant Apps Version- 1.22 and 2.12

As a workaround,

- I would suggest you to update the supervisor on you device to the latest and try to
  run the app again.
- Incase you still face error, submit your project to [Google's Issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues). (also, please share the
  link to that filed bug here)
- Did you check the behavior is any of Nexus Pre-O device, apart from OEM's Galaxy S8?